# rsync command used in jenkinsfile can't connect to remote server

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, rsync, jenkins-groovy

i have a jenkinsfile in deploy stage  i need to run  rsync command to transfer files to my remote server but always i have this message "connexion unexpectedly closed"  as you see in the screenshot , i added the jenkins public key in authorized_keys  in my remote server
so  i can normally connect using ssh from jenkins machine to remote server ,
but the rsync problem persist

```
    stage ('Deploy') {
    echo 'sucess rsync'
    def cmd = "ls & rsync -avzu  -e ssh  .  $server:$buildEnvironment"
    sh "$cmd"
    echo "you're here now"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As per the error which you have shared is showing that your fingerprint authentication ssh key is not got accepted.
I believe you are trying to connect the server for the very first time what you can do just add the below line in your config and your problem will get resolve

`rsync -avzu -e '  ssh -p 22 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'`

Comment: Thanks for you help but did it with use of server acess directly without use of variable $server:$buildEnvironment and it works fine

Comment: Save my day!! Thanks.

Comment: Hi fares sorry for late reply could you help me to understand more about your concern I'm sorry but I couldn't able to understand what if issue you trying to explain